# How to proceed user consent on amp-ima-video tag

Tags: amp-html, accelerated-mobile-page

Is there some possiblity to disable tracking and other user related actions while using amp-ima-video with data-tag?

I used the already known data-block-on-consent attribute but it seems to ignore the restrictions. (checked via Ghostery Plugin)

Any ideas?

Comment: Please file a bug report if data-block-on-consent doesn't work.

Comment: ok, thank you @Sebastian

Comment: You may file a report here: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues